# Is there a quick way to simply reverse a integer's number order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way you can reverse an integer's order more quickly than converting it to an array and than reversing it? For example, to convert `36827` to `72863`.

Comment: Convert to a string, reverse, and convert back again: `int(str(inputinteger)[::-1])`.

Comment: Also see [this code golf puzzle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/shortest-way-to-reverse-a-number), that comes to the same conclusion.

Comment: What should happen with negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the integer to a string, reverse the digits, then convert back again:

```
def reverse_int(i):
    return int(str(i)[::-1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> def reverse_int(i):
...     return int(str(i)[::-1])
...
>>> reverse_int(36827)
72863
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to `str` and reverse the string and type-cast it back to `int`:

```
>>> num = 36827

#                      v  reverse the string
>>> x = int(str(num)[::-1])
>>> x     # Value of `x`, reversed on `num`
72863

>>> type(x)   # type is `int`
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done arithmetically as well:

```
def int_rev(x):
    y = 0
    while x > 0:
         y *= 10
         y += ( x % 10 )
         x /= 10 
    return y

>>> int_rev(72863)
36827
>>> int_rev(36827) 
72863
```